# How to write descriptive conditionals for ifs?

Tags: documentation

I've gotten into the habit of using excessively descriptive names.  In addition, I've also gotten into the habit of creating the conditions for ifs like so:

```
bool user_is_female  = user.get_gender() == GENDER_FEMALE;
bool user_is_warrior = user.get_unit_class() == CLASS_WARRIOR;
bool user_can_wear_battle_skirt = user_is_female && user_is_warrior;

if (user_can_wear_battle_skirt) {
    user.equip(EQUIPMENT_BATTLE_SKIRT);
}
```

So, yeah, I dropped the "== true" or "true ==" that I've been taught was good practice. It seems to need less comments too. It is quite wordy/lengthy though. I was going for making the code more readable. So should I continue using this method? Any alternatives?

```
if (user.can_wear(battle_skirt)) {
    user.equip(battle_skirt);
}
```

Was a suggestion that I had to delete because I posted in the wrong place.

Comment: There are plenty of coding standards that you can study, to see what some more conventional coding styles look like.  What do you mean by "you posted the suggestion in the wrong place?"

Comment: Accidentally posted that question on "Information Security"; I wanted to give bonsaiviking credit.

Comment: Your method seems only OK for me. It's clear, intention revealing, easy to read. Keep on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conventionally, boolean variables start with verbs `is`, `has` or `can`.  This provides you with a visual marker that the variable is boolean.  You can use camelCase to distinguish between words.  So:

```
canWearBattleSkirt
isWarrior
hasMojo
```

And so on.

Your mileage may vary; each programming language has its own conventions for naming things, and sometimes they are similar, but not always.

That said, things like BattleSkirt, Warrior and Mojo might be a better fit as parameters to some function like `HasCapability(someCapability)`.  That way, you can treat the capabilities as *data* and not have them hard-coded.

Comment: I add the ">user<_is..." for identification and I use underscores because "IsMMORPGCSVFile" is kind of hard to read in relation to "is_MMORPG_CSV_File".  But that's just my take on things

Comment: Why do you need to know things like `user` and `mmorpg`?  Is the game not already an MMORPG, and aren't you already dealing with users?  To put it another way, is anything in your game besides a user avatar ever going to wear a skirt?

Comment: Well for things like *other* CSV files, like Monster_CSV_File or User_Stats_CSV_File.  But, yeah, only users would wear skirts...

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to move the decision to the individual item. Something along those lines:

```
class BattleSkirt : Item {
    bool mayUse(User user) {
        if (user.get_gender() != GENDER_FEMALE) {
            return false;
        } 
        /* ... */
        return true;
    }
}

if (skirt.may use(user)) {
        user.equip(skirt);
}
```

Now this leads to some duplication in different items. An approach there is to put those in some form of requirement classes. An item then can define its requirements and those can be checked.

```
class requireFemale : requirement {
    book check(User user) {
        return user.get_gender() != GENDER_FEMALE;
    }
};

class Item {
    book checkRequirements(User user) {
        for each requirement in requirements {
            If (!requirement.check(user)) {
                Return false;
            }
    }
};

class WarriorSkirt : Item {
     Vector<requirement> requirements = { require female() };
}
```

At first this is more complex but can make this way more re maintainable especially if you allow requirements to inherit from each other.